# Static helper class in struts action

Tags: java, struts2

we have small project which is written in struts. 
At one place I see couple of action class calls one static helper method from static class.

This the structure of the code

```
MyAction implements ServletRequestAware{
// this is the SMD method which we are calling from client side
buildCode() {
  Map<String, String> code = StaticHelper.validateAndGetCode();
}
}`

`StaticHelper {
public Map<String, String >static validateAndGetCode() {
initialzeVaiable(){
// here all the values are set to the empty values before build the 
// return map
....
}
}
}
```

`StaticHelper` have different static variables which are specific to each request. My question here does this is good design approach. 
Since variable are static in the class is their any possibility these might be goofed up when their are multiple request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going with static is not good design approach in your case, as the variables may varied request to request. And in multi-threaded environment it can mess up your code.

So suggestion is avoid doing static.

Create new instance of StaticHelper in your Strut action and call methods . .